# hadoop mongodb connector build failed

Tags: mongodb, maven, hadoop, gradle, mongodb-hadoop

I have installed hadoop 2.3 and the basic tests are passing with it. So, I believe that it is working. Now I want to install mongodb hadoop connector and I am following the official guide and when I issue this command until a certain point everything works then it fails.

I am trying to do it in a VirtualBox image of a ubuntu 14.04 with 15 GB of disk space and 1.5 GB of RAM.

Here is the whole log of what happens

```
 ./gradlew jar -PclusterVersion='2.3'
Downloading http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-bin.zip
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
Unzipping /home/shubhadeep/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin/4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7/gradle-1.11-bin.zip to /home/shubhadeep/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin/4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7
Set executable permissions for: /home/shubhadeep/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.11-bin/4h5v8877arc3jhuqbm3osbr7o7/gradle-1.11/bin/gradle

 [SOME MORE LINES, CAN NOT ENTER AS HITTING THE CHARACTER LIMIT HERE ]


Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.3.04/xml-apis-1.3.04.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.3/mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.4.0/hadoop-common-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-project-dist/2.4.0/hadoop-project-dist-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-project/2.4.0/hadoop-project-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-main/2.4.0/hadoop-main-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.4.0/hadoop-annotations-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava-parent/11.0.2/guava-parent-11.0.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/7/oss-parent-7.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/24/commons-parent-24.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.4/commons-codec-1.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/25/commons-parent-25.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/23/commons-parent-23.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/project/6.1.26/project-6.1.26.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-parent/10/jetty-parent-10.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-parent/14/jetty-parent-14.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-project/1.9/jersey-project-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/jvnet-parent/1/jvnet-parent-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.23/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/tomcat-parent/5.5.23/tomcat-parent-5.5.23.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-runtime/5.5.23/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/28/commons-parent-28.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/13/apache-13.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.0/jets3t-0.9.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-parent/1.7.5/slf4j-parent-1.7.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.8/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.8/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-parent/1.7.4/avro-parent-1.7.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro-toplevel/1.7.4/avro-toplevel-1.7.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/10/apache-10.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/google/1/google-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.4.0/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-common-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-servlet/3.0/guice-servlet-3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/extensions/extensions-parent/3.0/extensions-parent-3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice-parent/3.0/guice-parent-3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/google/5/google-5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-client-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.8.3/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.8.3/jackson-xc-1.8.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm-parent/3.1/asm-parent-3.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.1.2/httpclient-4.1.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.2/httpcomponents-client-4.1.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/project/4.1.1/project-4.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.1.2/httpcore-4.1.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.1.2/httpcomponents-core-4.1.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jamesmurty/utils/java-xmlbuilder/0.4/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/3/oss-parent-3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer-parent/2.3/paranamer-parent-2.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/codehaus-parent/1/codehaus-parent-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/1.9/jersey-guice-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-contribs/1.9/jersey-contribs-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/forge/forge-parent/6/forge-parent-6.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.2.5/httpcomponents-client-4.2.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-core/4.2.4/httpcomponents-core-4.2.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-parent/22/commons-parent-22.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.12.3/mongo-java-driver-2.12.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.4.0/hadoop-common-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.4.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-annotations/2.4.0/hadoop-annotations-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.2/guava-11.0.2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/commons-cli-1.2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-math3/3.1.1/commons-math3-3.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/xmlenc/xmlenc/0.52/xmlenc-0.52.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-httpclient/commons-httpclient/3.1/commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/commons-io-2.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/3.1/commons-net-3.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-util/6.1.26/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-core/1.9/jersey-core-1.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.9/jersey-json-1.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.9/jersey-server-1.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.23/jasper-compiler-5.5.23.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-runtime/5.5.23/jasper-runtime-5.5.23.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp/jsp-api/2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-el/commons-el/1.0/commons-el-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.3/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.9.0/jets3t-0.9.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-configuration/commons-configuration/1.6/commons-configuration-1.6.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.8.8/jackson-core-asl-1.8.8.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.8.8/jackson-mapper-asl-1.8.8.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.7.4/avro-1.7.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protobuf-java/2.5.0/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-auth/2.4.0/hadoop-auth-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.42/jsch-0.1.42.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper/3.4.5/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.4.1/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-common/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-common-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/extensions/guice-servlet/3.0/guice-servlet-3.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/netty/netty/3.6.2.Final/netty-3.6.2.Final.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-client/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-client-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-common/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-nodemanager-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jettison/jettison/1.1/jettison-1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/xml/bind/jaxb-impl/2.2.3-1/jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-jaxrs/1.8.3/jackson-jaxrs-1.8.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-xc/1.8.3/jackson-xc-1.8.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/jamesmurty/utils/java-xmlbuilder/0.4/java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8/commons-digester-1.8.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils-core/1.8.0/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/thoughtworks/paranamer/paranamer/2.3/paranamer-2.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/xerial/snappy/snappy-java/1.0.4.1/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/tukaani/xz/1.0/xz-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-api/2.4.0/hadoop-yarn-api-2.4.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.2.2/jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/inject/guice/3.0/guice-3.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/contribs/jersey-guice/1.9/jersey-guice-1.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-client/1.9/jersey-client-1.9.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/stream/stax-api/1.0-2/stax-api-1.0-2.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/sisu/inject/cglib/2.2.1-v20090111/cglib-2.2.1-v20090111.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/jline/jline/0.9.94/jline-0.9.94.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.5/httpclient-4.2.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.2.4/httpcore-4.2.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.6/commons-codec-1.6.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pig/pig/0.13.0/pig-0.13.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-net/commons-net/1.4.1/commons-net-1.4.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-runtime/5.5.12/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/tomcat/jasper-compiler/5.5.12/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/project/6.1.14/project-6.1.14.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-parent/7/jetty-parent-7.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jets3t/jets3t/0.7.1/jets3t-0.7.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api-2.5/6.1.14/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kosmosfs/kfs/0.3/kfs-0.3.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.4/antlr-runtime-3.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-master/3.4/antlr-master-3.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.4/ST4-4.0.4.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/pig/pig/0.13.0/pig-0.13.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-api-2.1-6.1.14.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1/6.1.14/jsp-2.1-6.1.14.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api-2.5/6.1.14/servlet-api-2.5-6.1.14.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/kosmosfs/kfs/0.3/kfs-0.3.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/hsqldb/hsqldb/1.8.0.10/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/antlr-runtime/3.4/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/ST4/4.0.4/ST4-4.0.4.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/servlet-api/2.5-20081211/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/antlr/stringtemplate/3.2.1/stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/servlet/jsp-api/2.0/jsp-api-2.0.jar
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-streaming/2.4.0/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.pom
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-streaming/2.4.0/hadoop-streaming-2.4.0.jar
Downloading Enron email test data to /home/shubhadeep/hadoop-binaries/examples/data
Download https://s3.amazonaws.com/mongodb-enron-email/enron_mongo.tar.bz2
extracting email data
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:jar
:generateScripts
:core:compileJava
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes
:core:jar
:examples/enron:compileJava
:examples/enron:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/enron:classes
:examples/enron:jar
:examples/sensors:compileJava
:examples/sensors:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:examples/sensors:classes
:examples/sensors:jar
:examples/treasury_yield:compileJava
:examples/treasury_yield:processResources
:examples/treasury_yield:classes
:examples/treasury_yield:jar
:flume:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':flume:compile'.
> Could not resolve com.cloudera:flume-core:0.9.4-cdh3u3.
  Required by:
      org.mongodb:flume:1.4.0-SNAPSHOT
   > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/cloudera/flume-core/0.9.4-cdh3u3/flume-core-0.9.4-cdh3u3.pom'.
      > repo1.maven.org: Name or service not known
   > Could not GET 'https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/com/cloudera/flume-core/0.9.4-cdh3u3/flume-core-0.9.4-cdh3u3.pom'.
      > repository.cloudera.com: Name or service not known

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 27 mins 12.948 secs
```

Can anybody please help me? I tried to browse the two URLs which are failing and repository.cloudera.com is browse-able while browsing to repo1.maven.org is disabled while I believe that is not a problem as I can see it has already downloaded a lot of things from there I guess.

Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what happened but running it one more time seems to solve this problem. I am able to install properly. No problem :)